# trigger pipeline for specific file changes

Tags: terraform, bitbucket, pipeline, bitbucket-server, cicd

I am trying to build a CI/CD pipeline such that it only runs when new changes are pushed to specific files in a branch. More specifically if changes are pushed to either  **terraform/modules** or **terraform/environments/dev**.
How can I include 2 conditions? If i do this, is it suggesting OR or AND?

```
condition:
              changesets:
                 includePaths:
                   - "terraform/modules*"
                   - "terraform/environments/dev"
```

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: 'Navigate to Prod'
          script:
            - cd terraform/environments/prod
          condition:
            changesets:
              includePaths:
                - "terraform/modules"
                - "terraform/environments/dev"
```

I mean, will it run when changes are made to both **terraform/modules** and **terraform/environments/dev**

or also when changes are made to either one of them

Comment: Is this for Gitlab?

Comment: nope, bitbucket @MohammedYahya